# Favicon is not showing for mobile Google search result when using Cloudflare

Tags: google, mobile, search, favicon

I already tried all instructions from Google regarding favicon. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9290858?hl=en

1. One of our sites is under Cloudflare and our favicon is not Showing in the mobile Google search results. Instead it shows the default "world" image.
   [image]
2. We have the same favicon "code" for other site without Cloudflare and everything is fine:
   [image]

We refreshed the cache from Cloudflare some weeks ago, and we asked also Google to reindex our home page again, but not success.

Maybe Cloudflare is blocking showing favicon in Google Mobile Search Result? I already asked them, but they said no.

Comment: It seems to be working now.  Perhaps you could post an answer for others.